# How can i use input fields as parameters to functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

So I have some input text fields and a button

```
<input type=text value="a"/>
<input type=text value="b"/>
<input type=button onclick=???/>
```

and I want to use the values of those text fields as the parameters in a function that gets called when i click a button, say

```
function foo(a,b) {
    dostuff(a);
    dostuff(b);
}
```

I don't know what to put in the question marks. So what gets the value of the text inputs, I don't think document.getElementById gets the value of them, just the element itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways to access those values, but the recommended one is to start by giving the input elements ID's.

```
<input type=text value="a" id="a"/>
<input type=text value="b" id="b"/>
```

Now, you can use `document.getElementById` to get the element, and then the value

```
<input type=button onclick="foo(document.getElementById('a').value,document.getElementById('b').value)" />
```

Note the use of ' vs " due to them being nested...

But you could also just pass the ID's to `foo`, and have `foo` do the `getElementById`-stuff.

Comment: The framework was set to 'onLoad', so the `foo` function was captured in a closure and not available in the global scope. Set it to 'no wrap' and you should be good.

Comment: Not all browsers (IE lte 4) support getElementById. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1945802/2225787

Answer (score 7):

assign an `id` to inputs and then call them with `getElementById`

```
<input type="text" id="field1" value="a"/>
<input type="text" id="field2" value="b"/>
<input type=button onclick="foo('field1','field2');"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(a,b) {
        elemA = document.getElementById(a).value;
        elemB = document.getElementById(b).value;
        dostuff(elemA);
        dostuff(elemB);
    }
</script>
```