# Getting a input by name then getting its value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the input by its name, then get its value, but this isn't working.

```
token = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken").value
console.log(token)
```

**The token:**

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="LXRZObY_ZLZ5pIjUd7fGgWONkAqJvXD6queBT3pod0ofwCXG2IhtEywSuaJOGVsjUIvKPyW60irAgP_fKslonLMFww41">
```

Comment: i think getElementsByName return as array.. so do document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0] should work.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945631/js-how-to-make-document-getelementbyid-cross-browser I bet it's a browser issue

Comment: Define "this isn't working" please

Comment: Look on https://jsfiddle.net/qwdbny7v/1/ best way to do it is use getElementById,or jquery way.

Answer (score 0):

the method "getElementsByName" returns an array so you have to chose the item in the array:

```
token = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value
console.log(token)
```

Comment: It returns an array-like nodeList, it's not actually an array. You won't have access to any array methods.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `[0]` to select your element value:

```js
token = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value
alert(token)
```

```html
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="LXRZObY_ZLZ5pIjUd7fGgWONkAqJvXD6queBT3pod0ofwCXG2IhtEywSuaJOGVsjUIvKPyW60irAgP_fKslonLMFww41">
```